# React update state after updating a different one in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to update my state after updating / setting a different state in my useEffect hook. So far it does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

The `isDisabled` logic depends on the values of the other states.

```
const OffersDialogueButton = ({
  type,
  status,
}) => {
  const { invitationType, status: cardStatus } = useJobPositionsContext();
  const { jobPosition } = useJobDetailContext();
  const [dialogStatus, setDialogStatus] = useState<CardStatus>();
  const [dialogType, setDialogType] = useState<CardType>();
  const [color, setColor] = useState<string>();
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDialogStatus(status || cardStatus);
    setDialogType(type || invitationType || 'default');
    setIsDisabled(
      (dialogType === 'invitation' && dialogStatus !== 'pending') || (dialogType === 'application' && cardStatus !== 'accepted'),
    );
    setColor(BUTTON_VARIANT_BY_STATUS[dialogStatus]);
  }, [type, status, isDisabled]);
```

Comment: You are not watching for dialogType or dialogStatus changes, add them to the dependency array and it should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When computing `isDisabled` and `color` state variables, you must use the new values of `dialogStatus` and `dialogType`.

```
const OffersDialogueButton = ({type, status}) => {
  const { invitationType, status: cardStatus } = useJobPositionsContext();
  const { jobPosition } = useJobDetailContext();
  const [dialogStatus, setDialogStatus] = useState<CardStatus>();
  const [dialogType, setDialogType] = useState<CardType>();
  const [color, setColor] = useState<string>();
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const nextDialogStatus = status || cardStatus;
    const nextDialogType = type || invitationType || 'default';
    const nextIsDisabled = 
      (nextDialogType === 'invitation' && nextDialogStatus !== 'pending') || 
      (nextDialogType === 'application' && cardStatus !== 'accepted');
    const nextColor = BUTTON_VARIANT_BY_STATUS[nextDialogStatus];

    setDialogStatus(nextDialogStatus);
    setDialogType(nextDialogType);
    setIsDisabled(nextIsDisabled);
    setColor(nextColor);
  }, [status, cardStatus, type, invitationType]);
```

Comment: Would I need to update my dependency array aswell?

Comment: yes, I updated it in my answer

Comment: So I do not need to put `isDisabled` and `setIsDisabled` in the dependency array?

Comment: I have one small issue which is why I am asking, like I pick a different classname wether isDisabled is true or not, on initial render the className shows properly but after loading completely (rendering) the classname is wrong. Not sure if that is a different issue or if it is regarding the useEffect update. Before my changes the classname worked properly

Comment: where do you compute the className ? It should work if you compute it when rendering the elements. If the calssName is wrong, it's maybe due to a mistake when computing the next `isDisabled` value in the `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

dialogType and dialogStatus are set in the same function with state `set` which is async so you cannot expect them to be set when you check them in the same function. You should have a new useEffect for those variables or have a local variable for the checks.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to make setIsDisabled by setDialogType , you need to use other useEffect

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsDisabled(
      (dialogType === 'invitation' && dialogStatus !== 'pending') || (dialogType === 'application' && cardStatus !== 'accepted'),
    );
  }, [dialogType])
```

setDialogType is asynchronous , you can not access it immediately after the setState.

Read more about React state here [State](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)